# Prime number inequality proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to prove that for every $n$ from $\Bbb N$ it is the case that $p_n \leq 2^{{2}^{n-1}}$.

I'm trying to solve it by absurdum so i took a counter example $n=2$ and found that is incorrect? is this correct or is there another way of doing it ?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** The standard argument for the proof of existence of infinitely many primes can be used to show 
$$p_n \leq p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot ... \cdot p_{n-1}-1$$

Comment: I just proved the existence of infinitely many primes but I can't link it with this question

Comment: @AnasSbouria Same proof. Look at $p_1 p_2....p_{n-1}-1$. This has a prime factor which is not one of the first $n-1$ primes. What can you say about it then?

Comment: I took a very good 20 min thinking about it haha I can't figure it out

Comment: @AnasSbouria Which part can't you figure out?

Comment: I understand the part of $p_(n+1)≤p_1p_2...p_n+1$ but I can't link it with 2^2^(n-1)

Comment: @AnasSbouria Induction.

Answer (score 0):

Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes goes as follows. Suppose there are finitely many primes, $p_1,...,p_n$. Then the number $p_1p_2...p_n+1$ must have a prime factor $q$ (possibly it is prime, but if not it has a smaller prime factor). We can check that none of $p_1,...,p_n$ are factors, so $q$ is a different prime.

It follows that $p_{n+1}\leq p_1p_2...p_n+1$ for $n\geq 1$. Can you use this fact to prove your statement by induction?

Comment: I just proved the existence of infinitely many primes but I can't link it with this question

Comment: If $p_1\leq 2^1$, $p_2\leq 2^2$, $p_3\leq 2^4$ and $p_4\leq p_1p_2p_3+1$, then what bound does that give on $p_4$? Does the same idea work for $p_5$?

Answer (score 0):

Showing that $n=2$ is no counter-example does not prove the statement. A counter-example would immediately show that the statement is false, but here there is no counter-example (because the statement is true)-

You can prove the statemment using induction and Betrand's postulate (for every positive integer $n$, there is a prime $p$ with $n\le p\le 2n$)